# Как сделать повторное воспроизведение аудио?

Tags: java

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы аудиофайл проигрывался вновь после завершения.

Библиотеки, которые я использую:

```
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
```

Я использую цикл while, булеву переменную и sleep():

```
boolean play = true;
            while(play) {
                playMusic("C:\\Users\\Ученик\\IdeaProjects\\Game\\src\\com\\company\\audio\\skeleton.wav");
                Thread.sleep(10);
}
```

Вот функция:

```
public static void playMusic(String filepath) {
        String reset = "\u001B[0m";
        String red = "\u001B[31m";
        //->
        InputStream music;
        try {
            music = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
            AudioStream audios = new AudioStream(music);
            boolean game = true;
            while(true)
                AudioPlayer.player.start(audios);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Can't find an audiofile skeleton.wav");
            System.out.println(red + "Error. Can't find an audiofile skeleton.wav" + reset);
        }
    }
```

После завершения аудио наступает тишина.
Аудио не проигрывается повторно через 10 миллисекунд.. Почему?
Как сделать повторное воспроизведение аудио?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте sun.*пакеты, это частные пакеты и не всегда могут быть доступны. Взгляните на этот пример , чтобы узнать, как воспроизвести аудиоклип.
Взгляните на ClipиClip#loop
Как очень простой пример...

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(...);
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioInputStream);
clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
clip.start();
```